# Do I need to follow these steps to connect Django to postgreSQL?

Tags: django, postgresql

Here is the [reference tutorial](http://blog.iiilx.com/programming/how-to-install-postgres-on-ubuntu-for-django/)

Do I need to create django_login and edit the file for permission?
I just installed `psycopg2` and edited `settings.py`.

So far it seems like I can insert to the DB and reading. So I guess I don't need to?
How can I check?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those steps outlined in the reference illustrate how to set up a new postgreSQL for use with django, assuming you have a fresh install and no users set up.

If you are running under a privileged account, like root, then it might be possible you have less set up to do for it to function. But the reason that guide exists is obviously because you must create an initial database, grant it access to a user, and then add the database name, user, and password to your settings.

In a nutshell, I would say that generally **yes** this process would be necessary. But follow that answer up with an *I don't know what your environment was before you started with django so possibly* **no**.

If you can successfully read/write to that database via django, then I would wager you are done.